# Building NumPy on RedHat

Tags: python, numpy, setup.py

I installed a local version of Python 2.7 in my home directory (Linux RedHat) under ~/opt using the --prefix flag.
More specifically, Python was placed in ~/home/opt/bin.

Now, I want to install NumPy, but I am not really sure how I would achieve this. All I found in the INSTALL.txt and online documentation was the command to use the compiler.
I tried gfortran, and it worked without any error message:
`python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95`

However, I am not sure how to install it for my local version of Python.
Also, I have to admit that I don't really understand how this whole approach works in general. E.g., what is the `setup.py build` doing? Is it creating module files that I have to move to a specific folder?

I hope anyone can give me some help here, and I would also appreciate a few lines of information how this approach works, or maybe some resources where I can read it up (I didn't find anything on the NumPy pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local version of python should keep all of it's files somewhere in `~/opt` (presumably).  As long as this is the python installation that gets used when you issue the command

```
python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
```

you should be all set because in the `sys` module, there are a bunch of constants which the setup script uses to determine *where* to put the modules once they are built.

So -- running `python setup.py build` issues all of the necessary commands to build the module (compiling the C/Fortran code into shared object libraries that python can load dynamically and copying the pure python code to create the proper directory structure).  The module is actually built somewhere in the `build` subdirectory which gets created during the process if it doesn't already exist.  Once the library has been built (successfully), installing it should be as simple as:

```
python setup.py install
```

(You might need to `sudo` if you don't have write privileges in the install directory).

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if I would have to use an additional flag (like `--prefix=~/opt`), but when I understand correctly, this is only necessary when I am using a different Python than the target python to install the module.

Comment: @bluewoodtree -- Not necessarily a different python.  (That could lead to problems if they weren't compatible versions).  One example is that you'd use `--prefix=${HOME}/opt` if you didn't have a local python and you didn't have write permission where python wanted to install the library.  Then you could set your own prefix and have your PYTHONPATH point to that directory so the system python could find it.

Comment: @bluewoodtree: you can use `python setup.py install --user`: it installs in `~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/...`This directory is already in you `PYTHONPATH` and is searched before system-wide directories (ps: pythonX.X is the version of python you use)